# Sharepoint 2013 List item operations take many times

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a Sharepoint 2013 list with 10000 items. In list item's editor panel, when i click on Save or Cancel button, take very long time for action completed.

Whereas in other list( that has 100-2000 items ) delay time of Cancel and Save operations is normal.

Because of this list used by another system, i cannot delete or move old items to another list.

Delay of Save operation make sense but why i click on Cancel button, i have delay?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is this on a single item or are you using quick edit / inline editing? Also, with 10000 list items, you shouldn't really hope for a solution on this issue since this is well beyond the recommended max items in a list.

Comment: It's single item. Delay of Cancel button has whats relation to list items count?

Comment: I'd guess that SharePoint processes each item in the list one way or another when you cancel the editing of a single item, since it might change the content of the list itself.

Comment: the view that displays your list, try using Grouped. Limit the number of fields displayed. Do you have a large number of fields in the List? Do you index applied? I have just tested this and it is not slow for me with two index applied and grouping enabled